# error description from http error code - react.js/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-status-codes

I have a Component in my `react.js` application, which display an error code.

Like this:

[image: error_page_react.js]

Now I'm displaying just a code, along with this what I want to to is - **show the reason of this error too**. Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) page contains a lot of information about error codes.

How can I do it ?

If I get any error, then I get the error code and use `window.location="/bad_request/".concat(err_code);`

In my `ErrorPage` component I've :

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.state.errorCode = this.props.match.params.errorCode;
    console.log(this.state.errorCode);

}
```

Rest is simple.

Comment: With the help of `Map<Code, Description>`

Comment: Can you post your code. Use the error object and use that value in jsx or the component.

Comment: @HarryJoy I was thinking, if there was any native way to retrieve description from error code via native method ?

Comment: @tarzenchugh I'm just passing an integer via url.. and I have updated the post..please see..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this to my java-script file :

```
let map = new Map();
map.set(400,'Bad Request');
map.set(401,'Unauthorized');
...
```

When I get redirected to this page, I just get what was the description of the error.

Now I have entered all the data manually, I was just asking if there was any automated way to log these.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error indicating that server didn't receiving complete req. in its time period So it is giving this error So you use increase server timeout as well as you can check with sending less data on server. For more info:
https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/408-request-timeout

Comment: What for `401`,`402`,`403` and so on... actually I was trying to dynamically tell the error description to the client. If you may read the question again. Can you help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

In common, HTTP response codes are being used for describing a general result of the response. For example, server should return one of 20x codes (200, 201, 202, ...) on some success operation or 40x (400, 401, 401, ...) on client error etc.
That said, code itself won't describe an actual request result in details so you have to do consider an error code only like general reference point.

Answering to you question, I'd suggest you need to take a following steps:
1. Review your server response structure to make it include an actual error message in response body.
2. Review your component structure to retrieve error message from response body to  display it (or perform any other required actions)